# How to add character in between values of a cell for every cell?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

[image: libre]

I am trying to add a character "-" in between the values into every cell for the Date column such as those in row 3 and 4. How can I do that ?
I am planning to format it into the date format like row 2. So I would need to add the "-" in order to do so.

Answer (score 1):

To convert the text to dates:

1. Select the cells that need to be converted.
2. Go to `Data -> Text to Columns`.
3. In the dialog, click on the top of the column labeled "Standard" to select it.
4. Change the Column Type dropdown to `Date (YMD)`.  Press OK.

For step by step screen captures, see http://cca220v.net/blog.php/2012/12/20/convert-cells-from-text-to-date-libreoffice.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an alternate solution. If you want your data to be identified as a date, then the above solution is complete. But I have had occasions when I need it in a specific format which the spreadsheet program doesn't provide by default. I don't use LibCalc, so wouldn't know if you did get a YYYY-MM-DD output format. If not, then this could be the way (though I am not sure it will get recognised as a date format, but mostly as text)

Your data seems to be in YYYYMMDD order. You can insert a column between A and B, and in cell B1, write this formula `=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,4),"-",RIGHT(LEFT(A1,6),2),"-",RIGHT(A1,2))`